# How to set height of ListView equal to height of all it's ListViewItems together in Xamarin.Form?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

Looks like I just need to set height of `ListView` equal to a number of `Items` multiplied by height of `Items`.

But how to get height of `ListViewItem`?

`myListView.RowHeight` just shows `-1`.

I declare `ListView` this way:

```
DataTemplate dTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
    StackLayout sl = new StackLayout {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        Padding = new Thickness(20, 10, 0, 10),
        Spacing = 20
    };

    var temp = new Label { FontSize = 20 };
    temp.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");

    sl.Children.Add(temp);

    return new ViewCell { View = sl };
});

ListView myListView = new ListView {
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    ItemsSource = stringList,
    ItemTemplate = dTemplate
    BackgroundColor = Color.Red
};
```

I use following structure (I don't use XAML):

```
<NavigationPage>
    <ContentPage>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <ListView>
                ...
```

That's how my page looks with 0 `ListViewItems` (size of `ListView` isn't changing with number of values):

[image]

Comment: StackLayout is simply enough; if your items total height is larger than screen height, the listview will be oversize.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your `ListView VerticalOptions` be set to `LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` so that it expands to fit all of its children?

**Update**

Your `LayoutOptions` should be set to `Fill` only, no need to expand. It will fit your screen height or a layout, if you define one.

Code:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", };
        DataTemplate dTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            StackLayout sl = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Padding = new Thickness(20, 10, 0, 10),
                Spacing = 20
            };

            var temp = new Label { FontSize = 20 };
            temp.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");

            sl.Children.Add(temp);

            return new ViewCell { View = sl };
        });

        ListView myListView = new ListView
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            ItemsSource = stringList,
            ItemTemplate = dTemplate,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red
        };

        this.Content = myListView;
```

Comment: Which element is the parent of your `myListView`?

Comment: I changed everything according to your code but `ListView` is still have fixed size. Only difference is fact my `StackLayout` have many controls as `Children`.

Comment: Hasn't your `ListView` have the same height as the device?

Comment: Sad but no. Added screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This string of code works kinda ok with my project but I highly doubt it's a good practice.

```
myListView.RequestHeight = number_of_items * 45;
```